# google api search results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api

Hi I am trying to use google app engine to create an academic project.
The mainly function I want to achieved by google api is search a user inputted query and return results then I can do further analysis about results. The xgoogle is my first try, but it has import error(I could run the same code locally) with google api engine. Even the xgoogle works I have no idea how to get the contain for different websites. 
I wonder if there is any way to return the google search result as documents. Thank you.

The code part is using regular expression to find contains in html code, but it could not work for websites which have different html layout. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from html import HTML_PAGE
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import re
import sys

from os import walk
from google.appengine.api import search
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from urllib import urlopen
from cgi import parse_qs

from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError


page = HTML_PAGE()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(page.pageChange())




class SearchFile():
    def __init__(self,userInput=''):
        self.__input = userInput
        self.__result = {}
        self.__files = []
        self.__filenames =[]
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk("dataFolder"):
            for name in filenames:
                path = dirpath+"/"+name
                self.__files.append(path)
                self.__filenames.append(name)
            break
    def outPutData(self):
        iterator = range(0,len(self.__filenames))
        for i in iterator:
            with open(self.__files[i]) as f:
                for line in f:
                    if self.__input in line:
                        self.__result[self.__filenames[i]] = line
                        break
            f.close()
        return self.__result  


class SearchFileHandle(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        userInput = str(self.request.get('input'))
        self.response.out.write(page.pageChange(userInput))        

        search = SearchFile(userInput)
        tramText = CropText()

        for key,value in search.outPutData().iteritems():
            keyBold = "<b>%s</b><br>"%(key)
            keyLink = "<a href = \"dataFolder/%s\" name =\"%s\"> %s </a>"%(key,key,keyBold)
            self.response.out.write(keyLink)      
            #print >>sys.stderr, "====>", re.search(regex, value,re.IGNORECASE)
            resultContain = tramText.tram(value,userInput)
            for word in resultContain.split(" "):
                if word in userInput:
                    for keyWord in userInput.split(" "):
                        if word == keyWord:
                            self.response.out.write(" <b>%s</b> "%(word))
                else:
                    self.response.out.write(" %s "%(word))
            self.response.out.write("<br><br><br>")    
        news =  TakeNews()
        for key,value in news.websiteRead(userInput).iteritems():
            keyBold = "<b>%s</b><br>"%(key)
            keyLink = "<a href = %s> %s </a>"%(value,keyBold)
            self.response.out.write(keyLink)
            self.response.out.write("<br><br><br>")


        googleSearch = WebSearch(userInput)
        results = googleSearch.returnResult()
        for res in results:
            self.response.out.write(res)
            self.response.out.write("<br><br><br>")


class CropText():
    def tram(self,text,word):
        regex = r"( .*? )"+re.escape(word)+r"( .*?\.)"
        #print >>sys.stderr, text
        if re.search(regex,text,re.IGNORECASE):
            return re.search(regex,text,re.IGNORECASE).group()
        else:
            return ''


class TakeNews():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__website = 'http://www.bloomberg.com'
        self.__topNews =''
        self.__topNewsTitle =''


    def setWebsite(self,website):
        if (website[:10] != 'http://www') and not('http://www' in website):
            website = 'http://www' + website
        self.__website =  website


    def websiteRead(self,userInput):
        webpage = urlopen(self.__website).read()  
        pathFinderTopNewsTitle = re.compile('<a class=\"icon-article-headline\".*<span class=\'headline\'>(.*)</span>')
        pathFinderTopNews = re.compile('<a class=\"icon-article-headline\" data-id=.* data-type=.* href=\"(.*)\"><span class=\'headline\'>')
        self.__topNewsTitle =  re.findall(pathFinderTopNewsTitle,webpage)
        self.__topNews = re.findall(pathFinderTopNews,webpage)
        result = {}
        iterator = range(0,len(self.__topNewsTitle))
        for i in iterator:
            if userInput in self.__topNews[i]:
                result[self.__topNewsTitle[i]] = self.__website+"/"+self.__topNews[i]
        return result

class WebSearch():
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.__search = word
    def returnResult(self):
        gs = GoogleSearch(self.__search)
        gs.results_per_page = 200
        return gs.get_results()


def main():
    app.run()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage),
                            ('/searchFile',SearchFileHandle)
                            ],
                            debug =True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: please post the full traceback of the error. you can't use `os.walk` on app engine.

Comment: @aschmid00 actually this part of code is working. the os.walk is for local document search. the error message is :    from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
ImportError: No module named xgoogle.search

Comment: there is no mention about `xgoogle` in your code. please update the question with the FULL traceback of the error.

Comment: @aschmid00 I find I did not add the module to the folder of app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bs4 module to the folder of app